# Understanding a complex series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

How can I understand this?
$$-q\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{p+nq}}{p+nq}=\sum_{n=0}^{q-1}\omega^{-np}\ln(1-\omega^{n}t)$$
 Here $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $\omega=e^{2\pi i/q}$ be a primitive $q^{\mathrm{th}}$ root of unity.
I can't understand it, I hope you can help me.

Comment: Have you tried the Taylor expansion of the logarithm?

Comment: Yeah word Taylor expansion works, writing up sol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm proving this as an equality of power series in the indeterminate $t$, where $\log(1-x)$ is defined by $\sum_{k \geqslant 0} - \frac{x^k}{k}$. Here goes (throwing out a minus sign): $$\sum_{n=0}^{q-1} \omega^{-np} \sum_{k \geqslant 0} \frac{(\omega^n t)^k}{k}  = \sum_{n=0}^{q-1} \sum_{k \geqslant 0} \frac{\omega^{n(k-p)} t^k}{k}$$$$ = \sum_{k \geqslant 0} \frac{t^k}{k} \sum_{n=0}^{q-1} \omega^{n(k-p)}$$If $k-p \equiv 0 \mod q$, $\sum_0^{q-1} \omega^{n(k-p)} = \sum_0^{q-1} 1 = q$. If $k-p \not \equiv 0 \mod q$, then write $x = \omega^{k-p} = x$, another nontrivial $q^{th}$ root of unity. We have$$(1 + x + \ldots +  x^{q-1})(x-1) = x^q - 1 \Rightarrow (1 + x + \ldots + x^{q-1}) = \frac{x^q - 1}{x-1} = \frac{1-1}{x-1} = 0$$(Note we can't divide if $x$ is the trivial root of unity). Thus this equals $$q\sum_{k \equiv p \mod q} \frac{t^k}{k}$$which isn't quite what you have, unless $p < q$...(otherwise you miss a few early terms).

Comment: :Thank you very muah! It's useful.